# Including external files in projects? (Aptana Standalone)

Tags: aptana

Is there a way to include a reference to external files in an Aptana 3 project?

Most of my work is in a dev environment on an external server, where I am pulling in, editing and then deploying files to a production server.

Creating files on my local file system to then figure out how to get them to sync to multiple different locations on the dev system seems like a challenge.

Any help appreciated,

pt

Comment: Have you tried synchronization/deploy features in Aptana Studio ?

Comment: I haven't, but I'm a little reluctant to do this, as my source files come from a wide variety of locations on the development server. It would be simpler for me to be able to include a link to the files, work on them in a 'project group' and know that saves are going straight to the dev server.

Answer (score 0):

I've not been using Aptana for long but to do this with a PyDev Python project I do:-

- right click on project root (in the Package Explorer frame)
- properties
- select the PyDev PYTHONPATH option on the left
- select the External Libraries tab in the main frame
- Add source folder button

...

If you're not using PyDev then hopefully the process is similar.